# Lambda and bind not working together in VS2010

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, bind

This code fails to compile under VS2010:

```
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

void test()
{
    auto f = [] (int) {};
    bind(f, 10);
}
```

It gives a long error pointing to the internals of `bind` implementation.
If I switch to a normal function instead of a lambda, the `bind` works fine, so I believe this is a bug in VS2010 but maybe I'm missing something.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems VC10 cannot cope with lambdas as arguments to `std::bind`. It seems to expect either a function pointer or a function object. I don't know whether this is a bug, but I suspect it is, since lambda function should become function objects during compilation.

Anyway, if you are in need of a workaround, this compiles for me:

```
std::function<void(int)> func = [] (int) {};
std::bind(func, 10);
```

Comment: Thank you for the workaround :-) After checking, I've found it's actually a bug: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/537984/the-bind-cannot-bind-lambda-expression-on-vc-10